# X2GO accessing laptop microphone

Tags: x2go

Ive noticed that X2GO has been repeatedly accessing my microphone in Windows Security Settings.

[Microphone Access.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZStA.png)

Does anyone have an understanding of whats occuring here? In the meantime I've disabled my laptops microphone.

Thank you.